# How to simplify an expression with special functions to zero

Tags: symbolic, special-functions, simplifying-expressions

The following is a well-known Bessel function identity:

$$J_{-n}(z)=(-1)^n J_n(z),\qquad n\in\mathbb Z$$

To check this, I used the following code and the result is as what I expected.

```
In[2]:= FullSimplify[(-1)^n*BesselJ[n, z] == BesselJ[-n, z], n ∈ Integers]
Out[2]= True
```

The problem is that *Mathematica* does not return zero when I try to simplify the following expression:

$$(-1)^n J_{n}(z)-J_{-n}(z),\qquad n\in\mathbb Z$$

I tried the following code, but the output is as complex as the input:

```
In[3]:= FullSimplify[(-1)^n*BesselJ[n, z] - BesselJ[-n, z], n ∈ Integers]
Out[3]= -BesselJ[-n, z] + (-1)^n BesselJ[n, z]    (*result I expected : 0*)
```

My goal is to command *Mathematica* to reduce the expression to zero, and I need some advice.

Comment: See also: [Why FullSimplify doesn't work here?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37347/534)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
FullSimplify[(-1)^n*BesselJ[n, z] - BesselJ[-n, z],  n ∈ Integers, 
             ComplexityFunction -> (StringLength @ ToString @ # &)]
```

Also:

```
ComplexityFunction -> (Count[#, _BesselJ | _Power, {-2}] &)
ComplexityFunction -> (Count[#, _?NumberQ, Infinity] &)
```

Comment: I daresay it is baffling that the usual approach of comparing `LeafCount[]`s doesn't work...

Comment: @J.M. `ComplexityFunction -> (StringLength @ ToString @ # &` could be useful at the code golf site

Comment: Actually, I don't know what `(StringLength @ ToString @ # &)` means. Nonetheless, I got some clues from looking at the other two options. The options you suggested are quite informative and could be utilized in many similar situations.

Comment: @Tom, it simply treats the expression being applied to as a string, and counts the number of characters in said string.

Comment: @J.M. Now I got it. That's quite a compact form.

Comment: @Ｊ.Ｍ. And why `LeafCount[]` doesn't work?

Answer (score 11):

A bit of cheating:

```
DifferenceRootReduce[(-1)^n BesselJ[n, z] - BesselJ[-n, z], n]
   0
```

I must admit I'm not sure why `FullSimplify[]` fails on this, tho.

Comment: Very nice. $\phantom{}$

Comment: That's a brilliant answer. Still, it's a mystery why FullSimplify doesn't work on this expression.