# how to simplify large expression with lots of special functions in it (BesselY, Hypergeometric, MeijerG etc...)

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions, special-functions

I saw this DE in Maple forum. When solving it using Mathematica 9.01, even though the result was correct (both solutions gave the same numerical answer for some random values), Mathematica's answer was much larger in size.

Using `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` did not help much (expression was still order of magnitude larger than Maple's result). I think special simplification rules might be needed?

I'd like to ask if there are other special simplifications to use, or commands I might be missing to reduce this result more.  Below is the ODE and Maple and Mathematica results.

Mathematica:

```
ClearAll[y, x];
ode = y'''[x] + (1/x) y'[x] - (1/x^2) y[x] == 0;
ic = {y[1] == 1, y'[1] == 0, y''[1] == 1};
sol = y[x] /. First@DSolve[{ode, ic}, y[x], x];
Simplify[sol]
```

Result is too large fit in the margin of this answer, so I zoomed in

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Maple:

```
ode:=diff(y(x),x$3)+(1/x)*diff(y(x),x)-y(x)/x^2=0;
dsolve({ode, y(1)= 1, D(y)(1)=0, (D@@2)(y)(1)=1});
simplify(%,wronskian);

y(x) = 2*x-(BesselY(0, 2)-2*BesselY(1, 2))*Pi*sqrt(x)*
       BesselJ(1, 2*sqrt(x))+Pi*(-2*BesselJ(1, 2)+BesselJ(0, 2))
       *sqrt(x)*BesselY(1, 2*sqrt(x))
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update**

Here is Maple result written using Mathematica notation in case someone wants to use to help find simplification to Mathematica solution. Also tried `Simplify[mma == maple]` suggested in the comments below.

```
ClearAll[y, x];
ode = y'''[x] + (1/x) y'[x] - (1/x^2) y[x] == 0;
ic = {y[1] == 1, y'[1] == 0, y''[1] == 1};
mma = y[x] /. First@DSolve[{ode, ic}, y[x], x];
maple = 2 x - (BesselY[0, 2] - 2 BesselY[1, 2]) Pi Sqrt[x] BesselJ[1, 
     2 Sqrt[x]] + Pi (-2 BesselJ[1, 2] + BesselJ[0, 2]) Sqrt[x] BesselY[1, 
     2 Sqrt[x]];

N[mma /. x -> 3]
(*3.33870606057436*)

N[maple /. x -> 3]
(*3.33870606057435*)

Simplify[mma == maple]
(* too large to post *)
```

Related question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25244/how-to-simplify-an-expression-with-special-functions-to-zero)

Comment: Interesting question, but what is your experience simplifying this expression with `FullSimplify`? Perhaps you could do somthenig like this `FullSimplify[expr1 == expr2]`, where `expr1` is the result of `Mathematica` and `expr2` - that of `Maple`? If it didn't work I would start simplifying  a few terms of `expr1` to get an insight what we can do more.

Comment: Try `FunctionExpand`. It might be able to expand hypergeometric and `MeijerG` functions.

Comment: @Artes my experience simplifying this expression with FullSimplify is that I let it run for few minutes and nothing happened, so I stopped the kernel. I was planning to leave it running overnight under FullSimplify when done using the computer.

Comment: @Artes To use `FullSimplify[expr1 == expr2]` one needs to know the objective `expr2` (which in this case comes from Maple) beforehand. Mathematica should be able to find `expr2`, or something similar, by itself. If Maple can do it, so can Mathematica!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `FunctionExpand` as suggested by Vladimir can improve the simplification, but for some inputs `FunctionExpand` [is very slow](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37293/using-functionexpand-to-evaluate-symbolic-derivatives) in this case `MeijerG` is the one causing problems. By replacing all occurances of `MeijerG` with a temporary symbol it is possible to get improved results quicker:

```
safeApply[f_, expr_, bad_List] := Module[{
   badOnes = DeleteDuplicates@Cases[expr, Alternatives @@ bad, Infinity],
   temp, cleanRules
   },
  (* Replace anything bad with temp[i], apply function and unreplace *)
  cleanRules = MapThread[#1 -> temp[#2] &, {badOnes, Range[Length@badOnes]}];
  f[expr /. cleanRules] /. Reverse[cleanRules, 2]
  ]

LeafCount[sol]
(*       5097 *)

LeafCount[Simplify[sol]]//AbsoluteTiming
(* 5.5s  1992 *)

LeafCount[res = Simplify@safeApply[FunctionExpand, sol, {_MeijerG}]]//AbsoluteTiming
(* 8.5s   434 *)

LeafCount[res2 = safeApply[
    Simplify[#, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, FunctionExpand}] &,
    res,
    {_MeijerG}]] // AbsoluteTiming
(* 9.5s   380 *)
```

Still a bit to go to reach `LeafCount` of 55 in the maple result.

Comment: very nice. These types of simplifications should be build into Mathematica I think.