# Using FunctionExpand to evaluate symbolic derivatives

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, special-functions, expression-manipulation

Some symbolic derivatives of certain special functions are not expanded automatically, but `FunctionExpand` often helps to get a derivative-free closed form expression.

```
Derivative[1, 0][BesselJ][0, 1]
(* Derivative[1, 0][BesselJ][0, 1] *)

FunctionExpand[%]
(* 1/2 π BesselY[0, x] *)
```

But for some functions, it takes too much time to evaluate. Possibly, there is even an infinite loop. For example, I left the following expression to evaluate overnight, and it was still running in the morning without any result or messages:

```
FunctionExpand[Derivative[1, 0][StruveL][0, 1]]
```

---

- Is there a workaround that could get an expanded form of the expression `Derivative[1, 0][StruveL][0, 1]` in reasonable time?
- Is there an infinite-loop bug in the implementation of `FunctionExpand` or do I just have to wait longer for the results (weeks, months, ...)?
- Is there any public information about what approaches are used by `FunctionExpand` to expand derivatives?

Comment: See `Low-order differentiation` here http://functions.wolfram.com/NB/StruveH.nb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the current version (10.3) is now aware of the Meijer $G$ expressions for the order derivatives (see [this math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1260611) as well):

```
Derivative[1, 0][StruveL][0, z] // FunctionExpand
   BesselK[0, z] -
   MeijerG[{{1/2, 1/2}, {}}, {{0, 0, 1/2, 1/2}, {}}, z/2, 1/2]/(2 π^2)
```

(The last version I used, version 8, was unable to do this, if memory serves.)

Nevertheless, `FunctionExpand[Derivative[1, 0][StruveL][0, 1]]` still takes a ridiculous amount of time (certainly longer than the purely symbolic version); I'm not sure if this is a bug.