# How to bail out from a non-applicable transformation function?

Tags: functions, function-construction, simplifying-expressions, symbolic, expression-manipulation

I provide a custom function in `TransformationFunctions` options of `FullSimplify` that can do a transformation only for some values of its argument. What is the proper way to bail out from the function and instruct `FullSimplify` to skip this transformation for the current argument when the transformation is not applicable to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually set up a wrapper function that transforms if input is valid and otherwise acts like `Identity`:

```
pickyTransform[expr_] := 0

helper[expr_] /; ! AtomQ[expr] && FreeQ[expr, _?NumericQ] := pickyTransform[expr] 
helper[expr_] := expr

FullSimplify[a^3 + x^y, TransformationFunctions -> {helper}]
(* a^3 *)
```

This works fine most of the time, but in [more annoying cases](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37301/1517) where the transformation function can be smart about expressions of the form `Thing + x_ * AnotherThing` even if `x` by itself would be considered non-applicable it can be useful to replace all non-applicable subexpressions with something inert and simplify that before replacing the inert subexpressions back to their original form.