# Why FullSimplify doesn't work here?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, special-functions

Since the emphasis of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25244/534) question is on finding a workaround, I decided to post this question with an emphasis on the *explanation* of the behavior of Mathematica.

The Bessel function satisfies the following identity:

$$J_{-n}(z)=(-1)^n J_n(z),\qquad n\in\mathbb Z$$

Accordingly:

```
In[2]:= FullSimplify[(-1)^n*BesselJ[n, z] == BesselJ[-n, z], n ∈ Integers]
Out[2]= True
```

However:

```
In[3]:= FullSimplify[(-1)^n*BesselJ[n, z] - BesselJ[-n, z], n ∈ Integers]
Out[3]= -BesselJ[-n, z] + (-1)^n BesselJ[n, z]    (*result expected : 0*)
```

doesn't work as expected.

Some workarounds were suggested in the [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25244/534), such as using `ToString` as the `ComplexityFunction` (in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25249/534)):

```
FullSimplify[(-1)^n*BesselJ[n, z] - BesselJ[-n, z],  n ∈ Integers, 
             ComplexityFunction -> (StringLength @ ToString @ # &)]
```

My question is: Why `FullSimplify` with no specified option value for `ComplexityFunction` (thus using the default `LeafCount`) doesn't simplify $J_{-n}(z) - (-1)^n J_n(z)$ to zero (with $n\in\mathbb Z$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that though [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullSimplify.html) does its best to find as simple form as possible in a reasonable time, it's not smart enough to handle all possible cases (and, actually, that would be an [undecidable problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem) in general).

But your indentity seems to be well-known and compelling, so I would recommend to send it as a suggestion to `support@wolfram.com`.