# FullSimplify doesn't work in one case

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

We have the following code:

```
FullSimplify[
2/33 (-11 HypergeometricPFQ[{5/6}, {3/2, 11/6}, -(x^2/4)] + 
x^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{11/6}, {5/2, 17/6}, -(x^2/4)] + (
11 Sin[x])/x)]
```

It doesn't work, but result is known, as it should be equal to zero. However, if we reformulate this problem as:

```
FullSimplify[
2/33 (-11 HypergeometricPFQ[{5/6}, {3/2, 11/6}, -(x^2/4)] + 
x^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{11/6}, {5/2, 17/6}, -(x^2/4)] + (
11 Sin[x])/x) == 0](*True*)
```

We get the right solution.

What is the reason of this strange behaviour?

Comment: This is not s strange behavior.It's normal  behavior,because MMA dosen't know the answer.`FullSimplify` have some limitations, it's not a perfect function,
but it's the best I know.

Comment: Quite likely, deciding wether an equation `expr == 0` holds true is much easier than calculating the value of `expr` without any hints. Note that `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` have to chose among a bazillion of possibilities to simplify an expression. The information that it could be equal to `0` provides a valuable information. For example,  it suffices to compare the Taylor series of the analytical expression at `x = 0` to see that it is actually equal to `0`. This is usually not so helpful for simplifying an expression.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher hm, it is really interesting information about FullSimplify. Thanks!

Comment: Many years ago someone wrote, I cannot remember who to give credit to, that people writing computer algebra software spend a lot of time thinking about `expr==0` and how to do that really really well. But "simplify this" can mean many things and might not include the particular code which would recognize your problem and simplify your expression to zero. Perhaps that explains what you found.

Comment: `Series[expr, {x, 0, 100}]` would suggest trying `FullSimplify[expr == 0]`

Answer (score 3):

As already noted, it is simply possible that `FullSimplify[]`'s (and even `FunctionExpand[]`'s) collection of transformations are not enough to deal with this problem. (See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25245) for another example.)

In this case, however, one can enlist `DifferentialRootReduce[]` to prove what is needed:

```
DifferentialRootReduce[2/33 (-11 HypergeometricPFQ[{5/6}, {3/2, 11/6}, -(x^2/4)] +
                       x^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{11/6}, {5/2, 17/6}, -(x^2/4)] +
                       (11 Sin[x])/x), x]
   0
```

(This is the mechanical equivalent of Bob's and Henrik's suggestions to inspect the Taylor series coefficients.)